# Typo3 6.2.3 fe_users mapping recordType issue

Tags: php, typo3, extbase

I am trying to map the `fe_users` table in `typo3` version 6.2.3.

```
config.tx_extbase{
    persistence{
        classes{
            TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FrontendUser {
        mapping.recordType >
            }
            TYPO3\Checkuserprofile\Domain\Model\CheckUser {
                mapping {
                    tableName = fe_users
                    #recordType = Tx_Checkuserprofile_CheckUser  -> this is deleted
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

However if the user is not in the `Tx_Checkuserprofile_CheckUser recordtype` the repository won't find it tried with `findAll() , findByProperty` with different properties and nothing,
is the recorType set somewhere by default so its required or how to map it so the recordType won't be needed?

Comment: Have you tried to set `mapping.recordType >` for your class CheckUser too?

Comment: @sreuter yes i did try for that too , eave tried recordType = 0 because i saw that in the DB tx_extbase_type default value is 0 , but same result it doesn't find the user's which don't have the Tx_Checkuserprofile_CheckUser recordType

Answer (score 0):

The following solution works!

One hint from the TYPO3 Coding Guidelines: Don't use the TYPO3 Namespace in your Extensions!!!!
So instead of 
**TYPO3\Checkuserprofile\Domain\Model\CheckUser** you should use **YourName\Checkuserprofile\Domain\Model\CheckUser**

```
config.tx_extbase{
    persistence{
        classes{
            TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FrontendUser {
                #mapping.recordType >
                subclasses {
                    TYPO3\Checkuserprofile\Domain\Model\CheckUser = TYPO3\Checkuserprofile\Domain\Model\CheckUser
                }
            }
            TYPO3\Checkuserprofile\Domain\Model\CheckUser {
                mapping {
                    tableName = fe_users
                    #recordType = Tx_Checkuserprofile_CheckUser  -> this is deleted
                    recordType >
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}
```